# Добавления сообщения при валидации Vue 2 с помощью ValidationObserver

Tags: vue.js, валидация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не могу понять как в валидации checkbox через ValidationObserver после отправки формы указать то что даынный чекбокс обязатателен. Пока получилось только сделать что бы он подсвечивался красным если не был нажат при отправки но задача что бы под ним выводилось сообщение. Так же добавил скриншот как должно выгдяжеть сообщение

код формы и файл vee-validate

```js
import {
  configure,
  extend,
  ValidationObserver,
  ValidationProvider
} from 'vee-validate'
import { required, email, min, max } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider)
Vue.component('ValidationObserver', ValidationObserver)

extend('email', email)
extend('required', required)
extend('min', min)
extend('max', max)

extend('password', {
  params: ['target'],
  validate (value, { target }) {
    return value === target
  },
  message: 'Password confirmation does not match'
})



configure({
  classes: {
    valid: 'is-valid',
    invalid: 'is-invalid'
    

  }
})
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="d-block text-center">
    <p class="text-left">
      {{ $t("main.header.sidebar.newsletter.description") }}
    </p>
    <ValidationObserver ref="validationObserver" v-slot="{ handleSubmit }">
      <b-form-invalid-feedback :state="!submitError" class="lead mb-3">
        {{ submitError }}
      </b-form-invalid-feedback>
      <b-form
        class="text-left newsletterForm"
        @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(submitNewsletterForm)"
      >
        <b-form-group>
          <b-form-select v-model="newsletterForm.gender" required>
            <b-form-select-option value="2">
              {{ $t("main.sidebar.genderMale") }}
            </b-form-select-option>
            <b-form-select-option value="3">
              {{ $t("main.sidebar.genderFemale") }}
            </b-form-select-option>
          </b-form-select>
        </b-form-group>
        <ValidationProvider
          v-slot="{ classes }"
          name="firstname"
          rules="required"
        >
          <b-form-group>
            <b-form-input
              v-model="newsletterForm.firstname"
              :placeholder="$t('main.header.sidebar.newsletter.firstname')"
              :class="classes"
            />
          </b-form-group>
        </ValidationProvider>
        <ValidationProvider
          v-slot="{ classes }"
          name="lastname"
          rules="required"
        >
          <b-form-group>
            <b-form-input
              v-model="newsletterForm.lastname"
              :placeholder="$t('main.header.sidebar.newsletter.lastname')"
              :class="classes"
            />
          </b-form-group>
        </ValidationProvider>
        <ValidationProvider
          v-slot="{ classes }"
          name="mail"
          rules="required|email"
        >
          <b-form-group>
            <b-form-input
              v-model="newsletterForm.mail"
              type="email"
              :placeholder="$t('main.header.sidebar.newsletter.email')"
              :class="classes"
            />
          </b-form-group>
        </ValidationProvider>
        <ValidationProvider
          v-slot="{ classes }"
          :rules="{ required: { allowFalse: false } }"
          name="checked"
        >
          <div
            class="form-group"
            style="color: silver; font-size: 0.75em"
            v-html="$t('legalNotices.privacyPolicy')"
          />

          <span>{{ classes[0] }}</span>
          <b-form-checkbox
            v-model="newsletterForm.checked"
            :class="classes"
            :unchecked-value="false"
          >
            <span>
              {{ $t("legalNotices.agreementPreffix") }}
              <NuxtLink :to="localePath('/privacy-policy')" target="_blank">
                {{ $t("legalNotices.agreementSuffix") }}
              </NuxtLink>
            </span>
          </b-form-checkbox>
        </ValidationProvider>
        <b-button type="submit" variant="green" class="mt-3" block>
          {{ $t("main.header.sidebar.support.send") }}
        </b-button>
      </b-form>
    </ValidationObserver>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import { defineComponent, ref, useContext } from "@nuxtjs/composition-api";
import { ValidationObserver } from "vee-validate";
import { NewsletterData } from "~/types";
import useError from "~/compositions/useError";

import { useCustomer } from "~/compositions";

const initNewsletterForm: NewsletterData = {
  gender: 2,
  firstname: "",
  lastname: "",
  mail: "",
  checked: false,
  skipConfirmationEmail: "false",
};

export default defineComponent({
  name: "HeaderSideBarNewsletterForm",
  emits: ["close-modal"],
  setup(_, { emit }) {
    const { app } = useContext();
    const newsletterForm = ref({ ...initNewsletterForm });
    const validationObserver = ref<InstanceType<
      typeof ValidationObserver
    > | null>(null);
    const submitError = ref<string | boolean>(false);

    const { addNewsletterItem } = useCustomer();
    const submitNewsletterForm = async () => {
      const newsletterData = { ...newsletterForm.value };
      const newAddressResponse = await addNewsletterItem(newsletterData).catch(
        (error) => {
          useError().handleError(
            error,
            (errorArray) => {
              validationObserver.value!.setErrors(errorArray);
            },
            (message) => {
              submitError.value = message;
            }
          );
        }
      );
      if (!newAddressResponse) {
        return;
      }
      emit("close-modal");
      let confirmationMessage = app.i18n.t("common.form.success");
      if (newAddressResponse.responseMessage) {
        confirmationMessage = newAddressResponse.responseMessage;
      }
      Vue.$toast.success(confirmationMessage);
    };

    return {
      newsletterForm,
      submitNewsletterForm,
      submitError,
    };
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.loading-height {
  min-height: 350px;
}
form.newsletterForm {
  .custom-checkbox {
    &.failed {
      color: #dc3545;
      a {
        color: #c30f21;
      }
    }
  }
}
</style>
```